# How to make sure node is run as a user?

Tags: linux, node.js

I want to drop root access to node.js due to security considerations as mentioned .
I changed the ownership of nodejs folder and now I need to make sure node is run as user abc

How can I confirm it?
I was referring the below link for dropping root access to node.js but could not find 
https://thomashunter.name/blog/drop-root-privileges-in-node-js/

> A common use for Node.js is to build web applications. Usually, we
>   want these applications to listen on port 80. As a security
>   precaution, most OS’s require root privileges for this to happen (e.g.
>   OS X, Linux, BSD). To run a Node application this way, we need to do
>   the following:
>
> sudo node server.js Then, the application runs as root for the rest of
>   the session. There are potential security risks to this, though. What
>   if there is a vulnerability in your application and a hacker starts
>   controlling your app and doing naughty things with it? Thankfully, we
>   can drop the user account running our process to a less secured user,
>   such as our normal account. There are two methods on the process
>   global which can handle this for us, .setgid() and .setuid().
>
> Here’s a working example of this in action. We want to run this code
>   AFTER we bind to port 80, so we run the code in a callback:

```
app.listen(80, 'localhost', null, function() {   // Listening   try {
>     console.log('Old User ID: ' + process.getuid() + ', Old Group ID: ' + process.getgid());
>     process.setgid('users');
>     process.setuid('tlhunter');
>     console.log('New User ID: ' + process.getuid() + ', New Group ID: ' + process.getgid());   } catch (err) {
>     console.log('Cowardly refusing to keep the process alive as root.');
>     process.exit(1);   } });
```

> The results of .getuid() and .getgid() will be numeric, and aren’t really 
>   useful, other than showing that
>   something happened. They’ll probably both say 0 the first time (that’s
>   root in *nix land), and then some bigger number afterwards

Comment: Did you read the code?

Comment: Yes I read the above code and for me it seems that code does the implementation.But I am unsure where and how I can run the program using command line on linux ? any pointers and help would be highly appreciated @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams

Comment: You don't. It's part of the application code.

Answer (score 2):

```
ps aux | grep node
```

will give you all the running node processes on your host machine.

But if I can say one more thing, never bind to port 80, even if you are binding as non root user. Change port to something generic (8000) and set up nginx as reverse proxy to handle incoming http requests and forward it to node on port 8000